# How can I get a value of an item from th:each after the page is rendered in order to send it as a request param (without using js)?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following code:

```
        <tr th:block th:each="participant, iterStat : ${participants}">
            <td id="idField" class="table-col-id" th:text="${participant.id}">ex</td>
            <td class="table-player-name" th:text="${participant.name}">example</td>
            <td class="table-col-operation">
                <form id="newTournamentRemovePlayerForm"
                      th:action="@{/tournament/removePlayer?id={id}(id=${participant.id})}"
                      method="post">
                    <button class="player-remove-button table-action-button generic-button"
                            form="newTournamentRemovePlayerForm"
                            type="submit">Remove</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

My goal is to send a post request to /tournament/removePlayer with the param 'id' equal to the participant.id from the row in which that button is clicked.

The table looks like this:

```
||id||name||action||
|1|john|remove|
|2|jane|remove|
|3|jack|remove|
```

However, in the current state, whichever "remove" button you click, it always sends the lowest id (eg. for the example table, clicking any remove button sends "/tournament/removePlayer?id=1").

I checked the Thymeleaf doc: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status

And tried using the following:

- iterStat.current.id (sends "1"),
- iterStat.index (sends "0"),
- and iterStat.count (sends "1)

But those would then always send the values indicated in parentheses.

Another possibility would be sending directly the value which was filled into the "idField", but I did not manage to find any way to do that in thymeleaf either.

Is there any way to do what I need without javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've messed up with `id` attributes. `id` should be unique across the page, but you don't change it while iterating. Therefore each `form` is identified as `"newTournamentRemovePlayerForm"` and each button is assigned to `"newTournamentRemovePlayerForm"` form. Since there are many of them it fallbacks to the first one.

You can either fix your ids or even simpler get rid of them:

```html
    <tr th:block th:each="participant, iterStat : ${participants}">
        <td class="table-col-id" th:text="${participant.id}">ex</td>
        <td class="table-player-name" th:text="${participant.name}">example</td>
        <td class="table-col-operation">
            <form th:action="@{/tournament/removePlayer?id={id}(id=${participant.id})}"
                  method="post">
                <button class="player-remove-button table-action-button generic-button"
                        type="submit">Remove
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Above should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks, it works!
I did not realize that assigning an id attribute to something that is created during iteration will have a consequence such as this, but thinking about it now, it makes perfect sense.
I removed the id altogether, since it was not needed (I copypasted the form from elsewhere in my code where the id was needed and forgot to remove it here).